# What is the correct way to add license keys to Hyper-V servers and guests?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, licensing

I have a Hyper-V server and I have three *'Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard'* licenses (ROK, not VL). I am wondering with what keys must I activate what servers with? Is the following the correct method? If it is, is there a better, or simpler approach?

Host: Key 1
Guest 1: Key 1
Guest 2: Key 1
Guest 3: Key 2
Guest 4: Key 2
Guest 5: Key 3
Guest 6: Key 3

Comment: That is the correct way to license the product, but I'm not aware of an easier way. Perhaps something at the deployment stage depending on how you deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is a Hyper-V server as you indicate, I would not use any of the keys for the host but install Hyper-V server there (which is free anyway).

But if you do want to do it like that - yes. With a limited number of standard licenses you basically must install keys in every guest and make sure you follow the rules as said in the licenses. In case of 2012 R2 standard that is - IMHO and as you point out - using them in max. 2 VM's.

THere are all kinds of other ways to handle licensing, but they all are only applicable for larger installations:

- Use a KMS (Key Management Server), requiting a VL key.
- Use AD licensing (putting the key into active directory), requiring a shared domain forest and... a VL key.
- Using AVMA (automatic licensing virtual machines form the host), requiriing DataCenter licensing.

With a small number of standard licenses you are limited to (manually) registering the license key in the guest, no other mechanism is available.

Comment: Instead of the free Hyper-V server, prefer Server 2012 R2 Core. It gives you the advantage of being able to install the GUI at a later time, if you should ever need it. In general, you stay more flexible.

Comment: The best approach is to have Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter license on a single physical host. One Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter license will allows you to run an unlimited number of virtual machines through Automatic Virtual Machine Activation.

To create a virtual machines, you can use pre-built OS image(gone through sysprep utility). While performing sysprep, you can use an answer file (that contains license key and other configurations) to configure unattended Windows Setup settings. This will allow you to create pre-activated virtual machines.

Comment: And that is where the idiotic thing like MONEY comes into play. Not sure you ether bothered checking prices.